# Low Latency FWFT Fifo in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have the below code in which I try to implement a low latency first word fall-through fifo in verilog.

```
   reg [width-1:0]       mem [depth-1:0];

   always @ (posedge clk) begin
      if (wr_en) begin
         mem[wr_pointer[address_width-1:0]] <= #1 din;
      end
   end

   assign #1 dout = mem[rd_pointer[address_width-1:0]];

   always @ (posedge clk) begin
      if (reset) begin
         wr_pointer <= #1 0;
      end else if (wr_en) begin
         wr_pointer <= #1 wr_pointer + 1'b1;
      end
   end

   always @ (posedge clk) begin
      if (reset) begin
         rd_pointer <= #1 0;
      end else if (rd_en) begin
         rd_pointer <= #1 rd_pointer + 1'b1;
      end
   end
```

I synthesize it and receive the following message:

```
INFO:Xst:3218 - HDL ADVISOR - The RAM <Mram_mem> will be implemented on LUTs 
either because you have described an asynchronous read or because of currently
unsupported block RAM features. If you have described an asynchronous read, 
making it synchronous would allow you to take advantage of available block RAM
resources, for optimized device usage and improved timings. Please refer to 
your documentation for coding guidelines.
```

Could someone explain the message to me? I don't believe that this requires asynchronous reads. I only modify the read pointer on a clock edge. Is there something else going on that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line below is your asynchronous read:

```
assign #1 dout = mem[rd_pointer[address_width-1:0]];
```

Change it to something like the code below to make it synchronous.

```
reg [width-1:0] dout;
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   if (reset) begin
      dout <= #1 0;
   end else if (rd_en) begin
      dout <= #1 mem[rd_pointer[address_width-1:0]]
   end
end
```

The asynchronous read you had means that all the words in the memory must be available at any time, as the memory address could potentially change at any time (not just at a clock edge).

Since the asynch read needs access to all memory words, the FPGA can't use an on-chip RAM. An on-chip RAM has a read bus which can only access one word in the memory, and changes on a clock edge. So builds the memory instead out of a bunch of LUTs. In that case, you can think of the memory as build from a 2D array of flip-flops, and now it can wire up to all the words.